# Combining rows from several tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am looking at writing a report in SSRS and I have hit a stump trying to get one column to work as I want it. Our database is set up with 3 tables, one with staff names and ID (Staff), one with role names and ID (Roles), and a dynamic table which links the staffID's with the RoleID's (Links):

Staff table

```
StaffName | StaffID
----------+--------
Tom       | 101
Dick      | 102
Harry     | 103
```

Links table

```
StaffID | RoleID
--------+-------
101     | 1
102     | 2
102     | 3
103     | 3
103     | 4
```

Roles table

```
RoleID | RoleName
-------+---------
1      | a
2      | b
3      | c
4      | d
```

I am trying to condense this down into an output to put into SSRS which would look like the table below:

Output table

```
StaffName | RoleName
----------+---------
Tom       | a
Dick      | b, c
Harry     | c, d
```

Unfortunately, due to the them being linked, I am finding it very difficult to get the desired output. So far I have a table which outputs the RoleIDs in the correct fashion, but not the RoleNames, like this:

```
StaffID | RoleIDs | Rolenames
--------+---------+----------
101     | 1       | a
102     | 2, 3,   | b
102     | 2, 3,   | c
103     | 3, 4,   | c
103     | 3, 4,   | d
```

To get this I am using this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Links2.StaffID,
    substring(
    (
        SELECT 
            CAST (Links1.RoleID AS varchar(max)) + ', ' AS [text()]
        FROM Links AS Links1
        WHERE Links1.StaffID = Links2.StaffID
        ORDER BY Links1.StaffID
        For XML PATH ('')
    ), 1, 1000) AS RoleIDs,
    substring(
    (
        SELECT
        CAST (Roles1.RoleName AS varchar(max)) + ', ' as [text()]
        FROM Roles AS Roles1
        WHERE Roles1.RoleID = Roles2.RoleID
        ORDER BY Role1.RoleID
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1000) AS RoleNames
FROM Links AS Links2
LEFT OUTER JOIN Roles Roles2
ON Roles2.RoleID = Links2.RoleID
```

Any help would be appreciated and apologies if the formatting is off.

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Please read ["How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so that the formatting isn't off next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rob, try with below solution,

```
select s.staffName,
         STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(r.RoleName AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
         FROM Roles r1  
         inner join Links l on l.StaffID = s.StaffID
         inner join Roles r on r.RoleID = l.RoleID
         WHERE r1.RoleID = r.RoleID
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
        .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
from Staff s
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly, thanks! Turns out it was the STUFF function I was missing out on.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the query on SQL Server but this approach should work.
Create a Temp table and insert Staff and Links related data in it. Then put an inner join on the Temp table with Roles table to get the desired result:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempStaffAndLink
  (
    StaffId INT,
    StaffName VARCHAR(30), 
    RoleId INT
   );


INSERT INTO #TempStaffAndLink
SELECT Staff.StaffId, Staff.StaffName, Link.RoleId from Staff 
INNER JOIN Link
ON Staff.StaffId = Link.StaffId;
```

This will give you both StaffId and RoleId in one table with StaffName. Now put an inner join on Roles table to fetch the RoleName:

```
SELECT #TempStaffAndLink.StaffName as StaffName, Role.RoleName as RoleName
FROM #TempStaffAndLink
INNER JOIN Role
ON #TempStaffAndLink.RoleId = Role.RoleId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
select StaffName ,string_agg(RoleName,',') as RoleName
from (
select a.StaffName,a.StaffID,b.RoleID,c.RoleName
from Staff_table a 
left outer join Links_table b
on a.StaffID = b.StaffID
left outer join Roles_table c
on b.RoleID = c.RoleID 
)x
group by 1
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code is doing and how it's a solution?